# Confidence interval and random chance

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I wonder what the relationship between confidence interval and random chance is. Let me elaborate a bit.
Say, I have the following linear relationship between two variables of $X$ and $Y:$

\begin{align}
Y&=\alpha+\beta_1 X_1+ \varepsilon.
\end{align}
Now, say, I get a  $\beta_1 $ of $10 $ which is statistically significant at $5\%.$
This means there is a $95\%$ probability that the relationship is correct and $5\%$ that it might be incorrect. More specifically, in my case, it means that with every unit increase in $X,$ my $Y $ increases by $10\%.$

Question: Can I interpret my result by saying, given that the coefficient is $10\%, $ my outcome is $5\%$ more than the random chance? Does it even work like this?

So, say, if I take the significance level of $10\%$ to account and my coefficient is hypothetically still $10,$ then is my result basically random and not strong enough to draw any meaningful conclusion from?

Answer (score 3):

This is incorrect, significance at 5% level [*does not* mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests) that you have 95% chance of being correct. Hence, the rest of reasoning does not hold.

I do not follow the rest of your question but you cannot multiply coefficients by significance level, it’s comparing apples to oranges, meaningless. Significance level is also *not*  something that you pick based on your results to “make” them significant, this would lead to flawed results.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I got my answer

Answer (score 0):

No, having a significant result at 5% does not mean that the result is correct 95%.

In linear regression you get a confidence interval on all the coefficients. Usually having a significant result means that the coefficient value of zero, that is $\beta_1=0$ is not in the confidence interval of the coefficient at a 5% level.

The way to interpret it  is that under the assumptions of the model, the chance of $\beta_1$ being zero given the data is less than 5%.

Comment: This interpretation of statistical significance is not correct, see the link in my answer in this thread. Significance is $P(X|H_0)$ not $P(H_0|X)$.

Comment: Confidence intervals are slightly different from hypothesis testing.

While in hypothesis testing we assume a null hypothesis and check if the sample is plausible as you said, when calculating a confidence interval we calculate it given the sample:
$P(v_1\leqslant\theta\leqslant v_2|X)\leqslant CL$
where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the confidence interval limits $X$ the sample and $\theta$ the true population value. $CL$ is the confidence level.
The interpretation is that given the procedure, 95% of the confidence intervals calculated by it will contain the true population parameter.

Comment: But this is slightly different than what you said in the answer.

Comment: You're correct.
How about the following edit:
Under the assumptions of the model, the probability of the true $\beta_1$ being inside the confidence interval is 95%